# how to detect invalid route and show 404 error in hapi js?

Tags: handlebars.js, hapi.js

I want to show a 404 view page when user is trying to access the invalid route which is not defined. for example if i am trying to access /myData then it should redirect to /404.

**server.js**

```
server.route(routes);
```

**routes.js**

```
 module.exports =[
{
  path:'/',
  method:'GET',
  handler:function(request, reply) {
    reply.view('index').unstate('token');
  }
},
{
  path:'/login',
  method:'GET',
  handler:function(request, reply) {
    reply.view('login');
  }
},
{
  path:'/login',
  method:'POST',
  handler:handlers.loginHandler,
  config: {
      state: {
          parse: true, // parse and store in request.state
          failAction: 'error' // may also be 'ignore' or 'log'
      }
  }
},
{
  path:'/register',
  method:'GET',
  handler:function(request, reply) {
    reply.view('register');
  }
}];
```

Comment: Please ask a question you've just described part of your code. Explain what is your problem and what error message (wrong result) you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide based on the response of the server like this

```
server.ext({
    type: 'onPreResponse',
    method(request, reply) {
      if (request.response.output.statusCode == 404) {
        //serve your page here
      }
      reply.continue();
    },
 });
```